# Angular ExpressionChanged error on calculated inputs

Tags: angular

I have a form that takes values selected by the user and outputs calculated values. As the user inputs data the numbers update. When the first number is put in it calculates `x + y` but `y` is current zero returning `x+0`. However, when the user enter the `y` value it return the error:

`ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'value: 215'. Current value: 'value: 163.4'.`

I'm using `ngOnInit` but I've also tried `AfterViewInit`, `AfterContentInit`, `setTimeout` in the function that does the math, and tried using `ChangeDetectorRef` but nothing seems to resolve the issue.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bupkrr

Add your weight then % body fat, you'll notice the error in console.

Comment: Minimal stackblitz which replicates this can help anyone look at it

Comment: @AkberIqbal stackblitz added

Comment: kindly check code without error in the answer, tc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only changes in the TS file below... Kindly check

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'phyto-calc';
  leanBodyMassValue = 0;
  bodyFatValue = 0;
  goalWeightValue = 0;

  constructor(private cdref: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {}
  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    this.leanBodyMassValue = this.leanBodyMassValue;
    this.cdref.detectChanges();
  }

  pctRange(low, high) {
    const x = new Array();
    for (let y = low; y <= high; y++) {
      x.push(y);
    }
    return x;
  }

  leatBodyMass(cw: number = 0, bf: number = 0) {
    this.leanBodyMassValue = cw - bf;
    return this.leanBodyMassValue;
  }

  bodyFatCalc(cw: number = 0, cbf: number = 0) {
    this.bodyFatValue = cw * (cbf / 100);
    return this.bodyFatValue;
  }

  goalWeight(gbf: number = 0, lbmv: number = 0) {
    this.goalWeightValue = gbf * (lbmv / 100);
    return this.goalWeightValue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can calculate `bodyFatValue` only if `bodyFat Percent` is changed

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-949enz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Here are my changes

**app.component.html**

*old*

```
 <mat-select [(value)]="cbf" ... >
   ...
 </mat-select>
```

*new*

```
 <mat-select (selectionChange)="changeBodyfat($event,cw)" ... >
   ...
 </mat-select>
```

---

*old*

```
<input
  [value]="bodyFatCalc(cw, cbf)"
  name="bodyfatlbs"
  ...
/>
```

*new*

```
<input
  [value]="bodyFatValue"
  name="bodyfatlbs"
  ...
/>
```

---

**app.component.ts**

*old*

```
  bodyFatCalc(cw: number = 0, cbf: number = 0) {
    this.bodyFatValue = cw * (cbf / 100);
    return this.bodyFatValue;
  }
```

*new*

```
  changeBodyfat(selected, cw) {
    const cbf = selected.value;
     this.bodyFatValue  = this.bodyFatCalc(cw , cbf);
  }

  bodyFatCalc(cw: number = 0, cbf: number = 0) {
    return cw * (cbf / 100);
  }
```